# How to fix php uploads only 1 row of a .csv, .xls, .xlsx files per upload?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to include excel or csv file upload functionality in my project. I used phpspreadsheet and I used the `fgetcsv()` function in php but all uploads well but it only picks one(1) record/row in all the file types. Please help!!!

This is my code:

```
// If the file is uploaded
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'])){

    // Open uploaded CSV file with read-only mode
    $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');

    // Skip the first line
    fgetcsv($csvFile);

    //generate voters id
    $set = '123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $password = substr(str_shuffle($set), 0, 8);

    // Parse data from CSV file line by line
    while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
        // Get row data
        $indexnumber   = $line[0];
        $firstname  = $line[1];
        $lastname  = $line[2];

        // Check whether member already exists in the database with the same email
        $prevQuery = "SELECT id FROM voters WHERE indexnumber = '".$line[0]."'";
        $prevResult = $conn->query($prevQuery);

        if($prevResult->num_rows > 0){
            // Update member data in the database
            $conn->query("UPDATE voters SET firstname = '".$firstname."', laststname = '".$laststname."', password = '".$password."', status = 'Unvoted', WHERE indexnumber = '".$indexnumber."'");
        }else{
            // Insert member data in the database
            $conn->query("INSERT INTO voters (indexnumber, firstname, lastname, password, status) VALUES ('".$indexnumber."', '".$firstname."', '".$lastname."', '".$password."', 'Unvoted')");
        }
    }

    // Close opened CSV file
    fclose($csvFile);
```

If I echo `$line` i get

```
8170123 fati abdu 8170124 faiza aliu 8170125 laila abdallah 8170126 lulaby wakil 8170127 fathiya napate
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your CSV file?

Comment: Did you try a simple echo of `$line` after each `fgetcsv()` call

Comment: So you dont limit the line length AND the data IS NOT COMMA DELIMITED :)

Comment: And there does not look like you have a line delimiter either

Comment: Doesn't really look like that file is a CSV at all.

Comment: when I echo each $line I get all the rows @RiggsFolly

Comment: i created the file in excel and saved it as a csv file @Dave

Comment: You can only read a CSV file with `fgetcsv()` ... CSV means `Comma Seperated Values` so the file would have multiple lines (delimited by a new line probably) and each field in a line should have a COMMA `,` seperating the values like .... `8170123,fati,abdu\n8170124,faiza,aliu\n`

Comment: Alternatively try `$line = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1000, ' ')`